# Android: How to Detect "Turn on USB storage" Broadcast?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect the **Turn on USB storage** using BroadcastReceiver though i am able to detect the USB connected using **android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED** action
and 
disconnected using **android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED** action.
How can i detect the **USB storage** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is how I check if storage card is mounted/unmounted. You can change it to check removed/insterted. I do this by register a BroadcastReceiver to get the "mount events" then check what state the storage card is in. If it is not mounted and is not while it is checking (the state during it mounts the card again) it is unmounted or the card has been removed.

```
public class MemCardReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            onMemcardMounted();
        }
        else if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING)){
            onMemorycardUnMounted();
        }
    }

    private void onMemorycardUnMounted() {}

    private void onMemcardMounted() {}
}
```

And in ManifestFile

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="the.name"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
            <data android:scheme="file" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

There are several different states [checkout this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) if there are any other stated like.  removed

Answer (score 0):

I think android.Intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT is broadcast when user takes the USB storage in use and ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED when it's turned off.